# MYSQL Query for the below

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot, max

I have join query which is not returning the result as expected. Below is the table structure, query used, result and expected result

**Table A:**

```
Id    Name    Token
1     A       abcdef
2     B       think
3.    C       Bxjscmsdnj
```

**Table B:**

```
id      TableA_id      configKey          configValue
1       2              pmt                ins
2       2              vat                gas
3       1              vat                nnnb
4       1              pmt                mc
5       3              vat                nhu
6       3              pmt                nnu
7       2              hit                bxhsjab
```

Below is the query that I used:

```
SELECT A.Token, 
A.Name,
CASE
           WHEN B.configKey = 'pmt’ THEN B.configValue
           ELSE ''
       END AS ‘PMT’,
CASE
           WHEN B.configKey = ‘vat’ THEN B.configValue
           ELSE ''
       END AS ‘VAT’
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.Id = B.TableA_id
WHERE B.configKey IN (‘PMT’, ‘VAT’) 
ORDER BY A.id DESC;
```

Result:

```
Token          Name            PMT           VAT
1              A                             nnnb
1              A               mc
2              B                             gas
2              B               ins
```

Expected Result:

```
Token          Name            PMT           VAT
1              A               mc            nnnb
2              B               ins           gas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation. First, add a `group by` clause that groups together rows having the same `id` and `name`; then, wrap the `case` expressions in an aggregate function such as `max()`:

```
select
    a.id,
    a.name,
    max(case when b.configkey = 'pmt' then b.configvalue end) pmt,
    max(case when b.configkey = 'vat' then b.configvalue end) vat
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on a.id = b.tablea_id
where b.configkey in ('pmt', 'vat') 
group by a.id, a.name
order by a.id desc;
```